# Adding a WHERE statement to an SQL query based on an IF statement

Tags: sql

Issue: I only want to filter the PropertySearch value if there is one

I want to be able to have a dynamic SQL statement based on this.

I have added If @PropertySearch which filters from a textbox on the webform.

The search works up to -- If @PropertySearch <> '' -- and will work if I comment the code

--

```
If @PropertySearch <> '' 
       BEGIN
           TblA.PropertyID LIKE '%' + @PropertySearch + '%' OR TblA.Propertyname LIKE '%' + @PropertySearch +' %'        
       END
```

--

I want to only filter the PropertyID/PropertySearch when there is a @PropertySearch.

I have looked at having 'AND' after 'BEGIN' as well as Nested tables but am struggling

```
If @RegionID = 1  --then  -- Head office users
    BEGIN
    SELECT TblA.PropertyID as PId, TblA.Propertyname as PNa, TblB.FireSafetyDisplay as FireSafety1, TblB.SlipsandTripsDisplay as SaT  
    FROM TbPropertyDetails as TblA inner join TbPropertyDetailsSafeguarding as TblB on TblA.PropertyID = TblB.PropertyID 
    WHERE TblA.RegionID > 0  

       If @PropertySearch <> '' 
       BEGIN
           TblA.PropertyID LIKE '%' + @PropertySearch + '%' OR TblA.Propertyname LIKE '%' + @PropertySearch +' %'        
       END 
    END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE TblA.RegionID > 0 AND (@PropertySearch = '' 
 OR TblA.PropertyID LIKE '%' + @PropertySearch + '%' OR TblA.Propertyname LIKE '%' + @PropertySearch +' %')
```

Comment: That would be two where statements?

Comment: no, replace your where statement with this one.. you don't need if